# Normalizing Data for PCA- Scikit

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, pca

I'm trying to normalize data before doing PCA, but I'm not sure I'm doing it correctly because the explained variance seems very small. My code is:

```
#Normalizing    
Data_Array = Data.values
standard = StandardScaler()
Data_SArray = standard.fit_transform(Data_Array)
Data_Standard = pd.DataFrame(Data_SArray)

#PCA
pca=PCA(n_components=2)
pca.fit(Data_Standard)
Data_trans = pca.transform(Data_Standard)
```

Is this the proper way to normalize data for PCA in Python? And when transformation is applied, is it still coming from the normalized data? Thanks!

Comment: It looks fine for me. You also have option to **whiten** the data in PCA. You can do something as following: `pca = PCA(n_components=2, whiten=True)`.

Comment: whiten in PCA whitens data **after** the transformation, not prior to fitting PCA.